# error message as first (unwanted) element of array in angular-nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, http, nativescript

having newly created a TNS Project with tns create myApp --ng and required the httpModule as described in the documentation -> i get my data from the JSON of my remote Server just fine.

**BUT:**

For some reason the first element of the returned array is the following object and thus producing errors later on:

```
JS: ==== object dump start ====
JS: 0: {
JS:   "__zone_symbol__state": null,
JS:   "__zone_symbol__value": []
JS: }
JS: 1: {
JS:   "id": 1,
```

and so on.

My Service looks like as follows (item.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Item } from "./item";

const httpModule = require("http");

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
    private items = new Array<Item>(
        httpModule.request({
            url: "https://www.example.com/data.json",
            method: "GET"
        }).then((response) => {
            var obj = response.content.toJSON();
            for (let i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
                //console.log(obj[i]);
                this.items.push(new Item(obj[i].id, obj[i].name, obj[i].role, obj[i].vereine, obj[i].testAufgaben));
                //console.log("items object testaufgaben: "+this.items[i].testAufgaben)
                console.dir(this.items);
            }
            //console.log(obj);
        }, (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        })

    );

    getItems(): Item[] {
        return this.items;
    }

    getItem(id: number): Item {
        return this.items.filter(item => item.id === id)[0];
    }
}
```

My imported Model looks like this (item.ts):

```
export class Slot {
    constructor(
        public slot: string,
        public fillIn: boolean
    ) {}
}

export class Aufgabe {
    constructor(
        public aufgabe: string,
        public aufgabeSlots: Array<Slot>
    ) {}
}

export class Item {
    constructor(
        public id: number, 
        public name: string, 
        public role: string, 
        public vereine: Array<string>, 
        public testAufgaben: Array<Aufgabe>
    ) {}
}
```

Anyone with a good idea what this error message is and what i can do to avoid it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What if you initialize it first? private items: Array<Item>[] = []; what does it give then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing `Promise` in constructor while creating `new Array<type>()`. anything passed inside `Array()` as argument will be added to the new array which will be created. that is why you get the first element other than the `item`.

try declaring `items` array first after that request the data from the server and then add it to the array.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Item } from "./item";

const httpModule = require("http");

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
    private items = new Array<Item>()

    );
    constructor(){
        httpModule.request({
            url: "https://www.example.com/data.json",
            method: "GET"
        }).then((response) => {
            var obj = response.content.toJSON();
            for (let i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
                //console.log(obj[i]);
                this.items.push(new Item(obj[i].id, obj[i].name, obj[i].role, obj[i].vereine, obj[i].testAufgaben));
                //console.log("items object testaufgaben: "+this.items[i].testAufgaben)
                console.dir(this.items);
            }
            //console.log(obj);
        }, (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    getItems(): Item[] {
        return this.items;
    }

    getItem(id: number): Item {
        return this.items.filter(item => item.id === id)[0];
    }
}
```